# Getting vectors of members from vectors of objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

I have the following setup

```
class obj {
  public:
  int a();
  int b();
  int c();
  int d();
};

std::vector<obj> obj_vector;
//Fill obj_vector
```

and I would like to access the methods (this is for an interface that expects vectors of ints, individually).

```
void func(vector<int>a ,vector<int> b,vector<int> c,vector<int> d);
```

I thought initially that extending the vector was the best approach, but have been warned against it.

I've implemented

```
get_a_vec(vector<obj>);
```

etc but this is a bit clumsy. Are there any nice alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The vectors aren't huge, so performance is not much of an issue, in case this influences the optimal solution.

Comment: Are you saying your consumer expects a `vector<int>` with four elements, or a `vector<obj>`?

Comment: Sorry, consumer needs a vector of obj.a, a vector of obj.b, a vector of obj.c, and a vector of obj.d. Is that clearer?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to "zip" a vector of tuples into a tuple of vectors!

Comment: @invisiblerhino: you've just made `a, b, c, d` methods and not data members when you put `()` after each.

Comment: @mr-tamer Yeah, this is closer to what I actually  have. Hopefully it's all consistent now.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function which retrieves the desired member from a single object.

Then pass that function to  `std::transform`.

If you have a `int get_a_member(obj&)` function, for example, simply call

```
std::vector<int> avec;
std::transform(obj_vector.begin(), obj_vector.end(), get_a_member);
```

If you want a more complex or reusable function, make it a functor instead. Then you can pass parameters to it in its constructor (for example telling it which member to return).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a generic function to extract any class member from a sequence of objects:

```
template <typename InIt, typename OutIt, typename Class, typename Member>
void extract(InIt start, InIt end, OutIt out, Member Class::*member) {
    for (; start != end; ++start, ++out) {
        *out = (*start).*member;
    }
}

// Example
int main()
{
    std::vector<obj> objs {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
    std::vector<int> ints;

    extract(objs.begin(), objs.end(), back_inserter(ints), &obj::a);

    std::copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: or you could write a functor and apply that to the vector with `std::transform`

Comment: I think he complains about having `a` as a `private` member, does this work even though?

Comment: What's Field? The solution looks good though, this is what I had in mind.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: They'll certainly have to be public for this to work. It's not clear from the question whether they're intended to be private, or whether the example code is missing a `public` specifier.

Comment: @invisiblerhino: `Field` is a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify public. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want a function that extracts the values of `a` from your `obj`s in a given `vector` and puts them in another `vector`, if this is true, then I suggest using a  `friend` function.

Declaring a friend function in the class `obj` allows this function to access `private` data members of that class.

```
class obj {
    friend vector<int> get_a_vec(const vector<obj>&);
    friend vector<int> get_b_vec(const vector<obj>&);
    friend vector<int> get_c_vec(const vector<obj>&);
    friend vector<int> get_d_vec(const vector<obj>&);     
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};

vector<int> get_a_vec(const vector<obj>& vec)
{
    vector<int> result(vec.size());
    for (unsigned i = 0;i<vec.size();i++)
        result->at(i) = vec[i].a;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why would you dynamically allocate the vector?? That's a horrible idea as it requires user code to manage the memory just to avoid a *copy* that is most probably not even made (i.e. it is optimized away)

Comment: To be able to return it, how else do you suggest returning it without having to pass it by reference? also returning it by value is very bad.

Comment: I think you have a misconception here. Returning an object that is created inside the function by value is not necessarily expensive. In all current compilers I know of, the calling convention for a function that returns a complex object allocates the object in the stack of the caller and passes a pointer to that allocated space. The function itself constructs the new object directly in the location where the caller expects it and no copy is made. By dynamically allocating the vector you have added cost (extra allocation) and complexity to the caller (need to manage the memory)

Comment: The above description deals with the copy from the returned object to the local object in the calling side. As of the copy from the internal object inside the function to the returned object, that is trivially optimizable in this case, and the compiler will *not* create any copies. More [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) and [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html) (Mental note: I should get back to writting some day...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Got it, it's pretty much useful to know that, Thanks :) but is this a standard (C++11 for example) or compilers just do it, and also how can I know similar compiler behaviors? (other than just facing it by practice).

Comment: The standard has a specific clause that allows compilers to do it, and compiler vendors implement it. As of how to know the details of the language/compilers I fear that experience and lots of reading are basically the way to go.